# Create Core context with GLUT/FreeGLUT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, glut, freeglut

I'm working on a project that utilizes `freeglut` and `GLEW`. In order to use the vertex and fragment shaders in my program, the minimum OpenGL version I need to use is `3.3`. I have checked the OpenGL version and GLSL version and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxpt4.png) is the result:

```
[cyclonite@localhost ~]$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL 
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center 
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel (R) HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.3.3 
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50 
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none) 
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile 
OpenGL core profile extensions: 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 mesa 17.3.3 
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30 
OpenGL context flags: (none) 
OpenGL extensions : 
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 17.3.3 
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20 
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

The OpenGL version string as well as GLSL version string for core profile is both `4.5`. However, it also shows that OpenGL version string is `3.0` and the GLSL version string is `1.3.` In order to use my own shaders, the version has to be `3.3` minimum. I tried to use `#version 330 core` at the beginning of my shader but when I run my program the following [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K8V1.png) appeared:

```
Cannot compile vertex shader. 
ERROR: Cannot compile shader. 
OpenGL Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.3.3 
0:4(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, 3.00 ES, 3.10 ES, and 3.20 ES
```

It seems that the program is using OpenGL 3.0 instead of 4.5, I have looked up online and someone said that `OpenGL 4.5 is only available if requested at context creation because compatibility contexts are not supported` was in the release note of `Mesa`, according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886548/making-sense-of-glxinfo-opengl-versions).

How can I create a core profile or request at context creation so I can use OpenGL 4.5 in my program?

I'm using Eclipse as my C++ development IDE on Linux operating system (This specific distro I'm using is PCLinuxOS).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `glutInitContextVersion()` and `glutInitContextProfile()` select the context version and context profile you want:

```
...
glutInit( ... );
glutInitContextVersion( 3, 3 );
glutInitContextProfile( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );
glutInitDisplayMode( ... );
glutCreateWindow( ... );
...
```

[Documentation?  What documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958770)

Comment: That fixed the problem immediately. Thanks a lot!