# MacOS GLSL Version '...' is Not Suppported (For All Versions)

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, linker, glsl

I'm building a game development framework in C++ with GLUT & OpenGL. To begin, I wanted to set up the scriptable rendering pipeline, since the primary function of a game engine is to store and render 3D scenes in a cross-platform manner. However, in my attempt to set up OpenGL I came across two (potentially related) issues. Firstly, I set up OpenGL to load the source from a relative directory––which failed for some reason. I triple-checked, and the directory was correct, but I had to use an absolute directory (which doesn't work too well for a game engine). Before I got to fixing that, I tried linking & compiling my source from said absolute directory, to which I got an error saying that the version I was using (330 for testing) wasn't supported. My code is super simple

```
// I changed this version to a variety of things, none of which worked
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
}
```

(similar deal with my pixel shader)

But gave me the error `ERROR: 0:1: '' : version '330' is not supported`, and similar errors happened for all version numbers I tried. The code I'm using to load it in is super basic as well,

```
GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
std::ifstream vertex("/Users/[REDACTED]/Desktop/XCode/Engine/Engine/vertex.glsl");
if(!vertex.is_open())
    std::cerr << "Vertex shader failed to open. If you deleted/renamed the file, please ensure your replacement has the name \"vertex.glsl\" and is in the same directory as the previous file was. If this still does not resolve the error, please try reinstalling the engine.";
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << vertex.rdbuf();
std::string bufferstring = buffer.str();
const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = bufferstring.c_str();
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertexShader);
```

(again, almost identical code for the pixel shader)

I tried a variety of things, namely changing the version number, rewriting everything, rebuilding everything, moving the files, testing a million crazy things, talking to copilot & chatGPT (who both said they couldn't figure it out), and rewriting every line over again to see if there was a typo somewhere. Nothing worked.

I set up everything with the following code:

```
void init(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 512);
    glutCreateWindow(project_name.c_str());
    glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0);
    gluOrtho2D(0, 1024, 512, 0);
    shaders();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    init(argc, argv);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(buttons);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

"display" is a placeholder, and I'm trying to remove it in leu of new shaders. "buttons" sets a char variable to current pressed button. "shader" contains all of the shader compilation code above.

[EDIT: I had a typo in the error message, said "320" instead of "330." I copied it from my most recent test, where I had tried 320––to no avail.]

[EDIT: Added information about window setup.]

Comment: How do you create the OpenGL context? What version and profile do you use there (if you set them at all)?

Comment: I used GLUT, and used this initialisation function:
```
void init(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 glutInit(&argc, argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
 glutInitWindowSize(1024, 512);
 glutCreateWindow(project_name.c_str());
    glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0);
    gluOrtho2D(0, 1024, 512, 0);
 shaders();
}
```
The "shaders()" function contains my code above, and after that I declare the KeyboardFunc and DisplayFunc (thought the second will of course be removed once I can get shaders working). I'm avoiding more heavyweight stuff like GLFW in favour of older libraries.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk I'll add that stuff into the original post.

Comment: GLUT is very outdated, supports only old versions of OpenGL and doesn't support Core profile (Core/Compatibility profile division was introduced in OpenGL 3.2), so you'd have to use something like `#version 100` (notice no `core`). If you use freeglut, however, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48472427/3162368) may help.